# TV display shimmering

Tags: tv

First, a video:

[image: Short scaled GIF snippet]

[longer, higher quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVzOy.jpg)

This is a closeup of my TV, of a still picture (the Xbox One menu)

There is no motion, the TV has all filtering, sharpening, etc disabled.

Could it be that the TV can't make the color range needed so it toggles pixels to approximate it? I remember software on the Atari ST and Amiga toggling between to images to approximate extra colors.

The TV is a LCD TV and the connection is through HDMI.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to write the obvious :) I added details in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your display implements some sort of [frame rate control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate_control), which is essentially the same type of temporal dithering you have seen in old home computers, but implemented in hardware.

Typically it gives you a "fake" 8-bit color depth from a 6-bit-per-subpixel panel.

Comment: ok, so that's what I was assuming; is 6 bit per channel standard in LCD panels or is it only the cheap ones?